# How to fix the d3 object?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, visualization

I tried http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc
However, I found when I used the brush, the main part of the stacked bar is out of boundary. How to fix it?
I think here is the reason:
[some bars should not be shown in the main part but they are still in the scope of svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXc2Q.png)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post your relevant code can make others easier to help you.

Comment: this is the link  http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These types of zoom literally are just geometric zooms, all the bars are still being drawn, it's just that the vast majority are off-screen, some are within the chart limits and a few lie in the axis gap in-between which are the ones that look awkward.

Make a svg clip, and add it to the right 'g' element to get rid of this effect:

```
  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "myclip")
          .append ("rect")
          .attr({x: 0, width: width, y: margin.top, height: height});
```

... and later on in the code

```
// draw the bars
        main.append("g")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#myclip)")
                .attr("class", "bars")
```

Comment: By the way, could you help explain the usage of url(#..). I am not familiar with it :-)

Comment: `url(#whatever)` just points to the element with id 'whatever' in the same document, it's how the clip-path attribute expects to see things. In this case it points to the id 'myclip' which is the id of the clipPath element we use to clip. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path

Comment: Thank you so much!